# How to create a hash function to mask confidential informations?

Tags: cryptography

In the current project I would like to create my own hash function but so far haven't gained much theoretical background on hashing principle.

I would be very thankful if anyone of you could suggest any useful resource about the theory of hashing, cryptography and practical implementations of hash functions.

Thank you!

*P.S. As hashing blocks of informations in this case is a part of larger research project I would like to create a hash function on my own and this way learn the principle rather than use the existing libraries. The informations I am working on will stay in house so there is no need to worry about the possible attacks.*

Comment: Study cryptography for a couple of decades or so, that'd get you started.

On a serious note though, don't try to roll your own cryptographic functions unless it's only for fun. A trained cryptanalyst will very likely break it in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Are you doing this for education/fun or are you genuinely wanting to encrypt important information? If the latter then **do not** try to do it yourself.

Comment: Hash functions don't encrypt data, they Hash it. There is no going back (unless you store the link and you assume there is only one matching set of data)... There are an infinite amount of data point for any one Hash, but using any decent Hash function you'll never find a set of two  datapoints that return the same hash.

Comment: Don't confuse hashing with encryption - they are completely separate techniques. Anything that is encrypted can (by definition) be decrypted. To be clear: hashing is **not** a kind of encryption

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Don't. Existing encryption and hashing algorithms (as pointed out in the comments above, they have little to do with each other) have been designed by experts and extensively peer-reviewed. Anything you write from scratch will suck in comparison. Guaranteed. Really. The only thing you'll gain is a false sense of security -- your algorithm won't be peer-reviewed, so you'll think it's more secure than it actually is.
2. But if you do want to know more about the theory (and gain an appreciation for why you shouldn't do it yourself), read "[Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html)" by [Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/). You won't find a better resource.

[image]

Brush up on your math first.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you use the right terminology, you'll be better able to find helpful resources.

"Encryption" is performed with ciphers, not cryptographic hash functions. You'll never find a reliable reference that mentions a hash as an "encryption function". So, if you are trying to learn about hashes, leave "encryption" out.

Another term for "cryptographic hash" is "message digest," so keep that in mind as you search.

Many chapters of an excellent book, *The Handbook of Applied Cryptography* are available for free online. Especially check out [Chapter 9, "Hash Functions and Data Integrity."](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap9.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own hashing function have you considered using a standard hashing function from a library and then salting the data you're hashing? That is common practice and ensures that anyone with software that decrypts data with standard encryption functions doesn't intercept your data and decipher it.

Comment: It says so right in the post (the 'P.S.' at the bottom)... :)

Comment: Yes I did read that, I just thought  that he might want to consider salting a hash instead of going through the trouble of writing your own hash function. They can get complex and most of the code examples he will find are going to be standard hashing functions like MD5 and SHA1 that are already in those libraries. Just my two cents :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said,  **do not**  make a new kind of hash (the code will get complicated and you might as well reinvent SHA1 or MD5.) Study cryptography first. But if you are willing to, look at existing hashes (most are based on another). Or you can look at the hash model. The hash model looks like:

1. A mixing stage (mix up the contents and modify)
2. A combining stage (combine the data in the mixing stage with the initial state [the original hash])

Or maybe start with something simple and build up from it (to make a secure hash).

Comment: By the way, I'm having the same problem too. The easy-to-implement cryptographic algorithms have a patent on them and the others are hard to implement! By the way, I'm also creating a reversible hash function in the process (you can get the original code with the message digest). Also, I would create my own cryptographic hash functions (my version is the only hash that is reversible when an attacker cannot reverse it).